# Get black image but i don't know why

Tags: python, image, opencv, pdf, pymupdf

The following codes gives me a nearly black image

```
import fitz
import cv2 #opencv for preprocessing of image
import numpy as np
filename = 'sample_pdf\muscle model\Invoice of muscle model from HealthLink.pdf'

doc = fitz.Document(filename) #same as fitz.open

page1 = doc[0]
pix = page1.get_pixmap(colorspace='RGB', annots=False)
bytes = np.frombuffer(pix.samples, dtype=np.int8) 
img_rgb = bytes.reshape(pix.height, pix.width, pix.n)
img_bgr = img_rgb[:,:,::-1]#convert from rgb to bgr for cv2.imwrite
cv2.imwrite('test.png', img_bgr)

doc.close()
```

[image: test.png]

I know there could be other functions that can turn a page in PDF to an image. But i still wonder why the above codes fails.

Comment: `img_rgb[:,:,::-1]` -- OpenCV doesn't understand the numpy arrays this operation produces. Make a deep copy of the result before passing it to `imwrite`, or use `cvtColor` instead to change from RGB to BGR.

Comment: @Dan Mašek could add some details? If I delegate the conversion to `cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)` I got an error back

Comment: @cards What error? | A call to the [`copy`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.copy.html#numpy.ndarray.copy) member function of the resulting numpy array should do it. Problem is that the indexing operation just creates a new "view" (only changes the metadata describing how the pixel buffer should be read). In this case it's an equivalent of "read the third dimension in reverse order". OpenCV wrappers can't deal with negative strides that this results in. A deep copy resets all the strides to a "normal" way, by copying the pixel buffer in the defined order.

Comment: @Dan Mašek
 `> Unsupported depth of input image:
>     'VDepth::contains(depth)'
> where
>     'depth' is 1 (CV_8S)` when adding `img_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)`

Comment: @Cards: Oh, OK. That one is easily fixed, that particular problem is caused by the specification of inappropriate `dtype` in `bytes = np.frombuffer(pix.samples, dtype=np.int8)`. Change that to `np.uint8`, that should solve it -- OpenCV expects unsigned 8-bit integers.

Comment: @Dan Mašek That is it! The wrong datatype was the cause of the issue! So by only changing to `uint8` the problem is solved, no even need to use `cv2.cvtColor` or deepcopy!

Comment: @cards Interesting, maybe the wrappers got an improvement recently, I'll have to have a look again, it's been a while since I dug through that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by *Dan Mašek* the cause of the issue is the wrong datatype passed to the `numpy.frombuffer` function: instead of `int8` it should be `uint8`.

Intensity of the image's pixels are, normally,

- *positive integers* between 0-255 or
- *floating* numbers between 0-1.

With `int8` positivity is not grant and data seems to be centred around the origin, from -127 to +128.

Comment: You might want to extend this with reference to [`cvtColor`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.9.0/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab) which specifies that the supported formats are 8-bit or 16-bit unsigned integers, or 32-bit floats.